# Работа с большими файлам

Tags: windows, шаблоны-проектирования, c++, шифрование, файлы

Мне нужно зашифровать файл.

Самое простое, что мне пришло в голову, это просто прочитать  файл, и записать его например в переменную типа string. Потом зашифровать данные в этой переменной. Очистить файл, и записать туда модифицированный данный из этой переменной.

**Но проблема в том, что файл может значительно превышать размеры оперативной памяти.**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как принято работать с большими файлами(читать, писать)? Если кто нибудь сможет скинуть код на С++, будет вообще классно.

Comment: а почему нельзя прочитать 4килобайта, зашифровать, записать, потом следующие 4к.  Главное только остаток правильно обработать.

Большинство алгоритмов шифрования хорошо работает с подобным - оно называется "поточное шифрование". Единственное, что некоторые алгоритмы шифруют эти куски (их называют блоки) независимо (то есть одинаковые блоки будут зашифрованы одинаковыми последовательностями) и связанное шифрование - когда после шифрования блока остается некоторый остаток, который используется для шифрования следующего.

Answer (score 4):

[@vvtvvtvvt](/users/14942/vvtvvtvvt), все зависит от метода шифрования. Для большинства случаев абсолютно подходит способ, предложенный [@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim). А можете не использовать буферизацию явно, она уже "заложена" в библиотечные функции работы с файлами.

Простой пример подобной программы на  Си. (Можете потренироваться и перевести сами на C++ streams).

```
// Простое потоковое шифрование файла любой длины на том же месте
// ./a.out filename [password]
// для расшифровки запустить еще раз с тем же password
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac < 2) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s filename [password]\n", av[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  char *fname, *pass;
  fname = av[1];
  pass = av[2] ? av[2] : fname;

  FILE *in = fopen(fname, "r"), 
    *out = fopen(fname, "r+"); // чтение и запись БЕЗ УРЕЗАНИЯ файла
  if (!in || !out) {
    perror(fname);
    return 2;
  }
  rewind(out); // требуется для перевода файла в режим записи

  int c, i = 0, l = strlen(pass);
  while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) {
    c ^= pass[i];
    fputc(c, out);
    i = (++i) % l; // циклически перебираем символы pass
  }

  return fclose(out) + fclose(in); 
}
```

Кстати, g++ тоже ее компилирует.

При желании можете усложнить (несколько усилить) такой алгоритм. Например, можно вычислять HASH(pass)  и шифровать им, перевычисляя HASH(предыдущий HASH) каждый раз, когда прочли N символов (допустим, размер HASH).